# C function definition and declaration matching in different files

Tags: c, declaration, definition

I'm learning C after a little coding in Java and C++, I've just asked this question about ANSI and old-style C function definitions/declarations
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701579/c-function-definition-and-declaration)
.

I understand that if I don't declare a function,it is deduced from context,when I call it,to be `int function()` with a arbitrary number of arguments, and that if I provide a definition for it in the same file,as long as it declares a int return type it can take any arguments (nothing is assumed at the declaration).

Now, I understand that standard C avoids this syntax,it being error-prone and generally a receipt for trouble. So I use a proper function prototype as `int function(void)` (assuming I want a function that takes no arguments), and I can call it only as `function()` and the compiler enforces a subsequent definition to be `int function(){....}` and nothing else.

But... 
if I define the function in another compilation unit,it compiles (and links) even if the parameter list doesn't match or even if the return type doesn't!
I assume this lead to undefined behaviour?

can someone explain me this behaviour?
why doesn't the compiler enforces something to avoid all this (as in C++)?

Comment: If that's not a duplicate, then search for 'c function prototype mismatch'

Comment: "I understand that if I don't declare a function,it is deduced from context" - that was only true in C89. For the last 16 years it's been an error to use a function without declaration.